# Is it possible to change `ng serve` config in angular-cli (i want to add some rule, so some requests will be redirected to another port)?

Tags: javascript, angular, express, angular-cli

I am creating small Angular 2 + TypeScript example. [Here](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-goods-list/tree/feature/add-goods) is the code.

I need some really simple backend stub now. What I want to do. I want to create `expressjs` server on `localhost:3000` for example. And I want to modify `ng serve` config, so if I ask `localhost:4200/api/x/y/z` this request will be redirected to `localhost:3000/x/y/z`.

What I want to achieve? This will allow me to make http request to `/api/x/y/z` in my Angular application. Web server will make redirect to express backend. Express will handle and generate some json etc.

Why I don't want to just make request to `localhost:3000/x/y/z`? As I remember there will be some problems because of CORS.

May be there is another way to achieve what I want? Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't have to do that. Your frontend app will run on 4200 while you can make requests with http as you normally would by calling 3000. I've done this many many times and it works.

Comment: I need --proxy-config option for it

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I don't think this is good idea to make such requests. The reason is that in real life you would not be able it. You will have your server configured to redirect `/api` (or smth like this) requests to another host or another port (to your backend).

Comment: It depends. It has always worked for us but I'm not 100% on the backend config that's been made. But I've never had to use proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--proxy-config` options is the answer

1. Add `cli-profy.conf.json` with this contents:

   {
     "/api": {
       "target": "http://localhost:3000/",
       "secure": false
     }
   }
2. Change `start` script to this: `ng serve --open --proxy-config cli-proxy.conf.json`
3. Run `npm start`.

Now all requests to `localhost:4200/api/` will be passed to `localhost:3000/api`.